# Calling a method in Watch ExtensionDelegate

Tags: swift2, watchkit, watch

How do you call a method in the Watch ExtensionDelegate from an interface controller?

For the life of me I cannot get it to work?

So, ExtensionDelegate.mymethod(string:param)

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you get an instance of your watchkit delegate:

```
let myDelegate = WKExtension.sharedExtension().delegate as! ExtensionDelegate
```

You can call your methods on this object.

Comment: Thanks a million ;-)

Comment: Ever run into a problem on the ComplicationController side where you can't seem to get the data you set in the ExtensionDelegate via WCSession: to be pulled? Thats what I'm getting stuck on right now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542729/call-extensiondelegate-to-create-refresh-data-for-complication

Comment: have not used complications yet, sorry